# How to align the button at right side?

Tags: android

May i know how do i align the Button just beside these three Textviews? Instead of just below the Textviews. 
This is the XML file.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:background="#000000">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="Textview1" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Textview2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/Textview2" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Textview3" android:id="@+id/Textview3" />

        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="70px"
                android:layout_height="38px" android:text="Button"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO you should put the three textviews and the button in the RelativeLayout, and get rid of the LinearLayout. There's no point in having two layouts when you can get by with just one, as each ViewGroup adds overhead to the layout and draw passes. Do:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv2" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@id/tv1"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv3" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_below="@id/tv2"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I didn't compile this, but it should do what you need. Play around with the layout parameters you give button (you can align it to the top and right of the parent, or to the right of any of the textboxes, etc...).

The RelativeLayout is very powerful; you should really take advantage of it's flexibility.

Comment: i set the button to the right of tv3. then tv1 and tv2 overwrite each other.

Answer (score 4):

use the attribut for your `Button` : `android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"` ,

so the xml code for your `Button` will be like this :

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button" 
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="38px" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" <!-- align the Button on the right side -->
 />
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just put the button below the three textboxes, aligned to the right side of the screen?

Comment: Can align the button such that it's at the "Center" right side of the textview? Because i have three textviews, the button used to be at the bottom now that after i use the alignParentRight, it's still at the bottom but align to right.

Comment: @noobler : the three textViews are putted on a linearLayout , and the user guy want to align the Button to the right side

Comment: @user1058153 : you want your Button Just After a Specific TextView ??? Tell me which TextView you Want to put your Button bellow it , and just move the Code of your RelativeLayout , and put it after the Code of the TextView that you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question title suggest you just want to align the button to the right side of the screen. In that case, the other answers are fine. In your question, though, you say you want your button 'beside' the Textviews. In that case, read the following:

Your outer `LinearLayout` is vertically oriented, so all of its direct children will be below each other. Depending on exactly how you want this to look, you may want to nest a horizontal `LinearLayout` outside or inside your current `LinearLayout`.

A `RelativeLayout` positions its children relative to each other, not relative to stuff outside of it. Maybe you want something along these lines (I did not try to compile this):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
        android:background="#000000">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="38px" android:text="Button" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textview1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:text="Textview1" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Textview2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/Textview2" />

            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Textview3" android:id="@+id/Textview3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```